# How can I submit a form if a condition is met using Angular?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-ng-if

I would like to submit the following form if `selected` equals `true`.

```
<form *ngIf="selected" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
  <!-- Child elements of the form... -->
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        [disabled]="!f.valid"
        (click)="onClick()"
      >Save
      </button>
  </form>
```

However, the following error is thrown.

```
Form submission cancelled because the form is not connected.
```

Without `*ngIf="selected"` the forms works as aspected. I presume it throws the error because `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm"` is not initialised when the page is loaded.

How can I submit the form if `selected` equals `true` using `*ngIf`?

Comment: It works for me in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dmgb00LKgaPaEz0iohFE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend adding the structural directive `*ngIf` as an attribute of an `ng-container` element as follows.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
    <ng-container *ngIf="selected">
        <!-- Form children... -->
    </ng-container>
</form>
```